# Audio only plays out right channel

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio

After a recent software update, audio now plays only out of the right channel (the left channel is now silent).  I am running Fedora Linux 30, and the only obviously relevant software that changed was updating the Linux kernel (from 5.1.17-300 to 5.2.16-200, I think).  It doesn't appear to be a problem with my headphones.

I notice that if I go into Pulseaudio Volume Control app, enter the Configuration tab, and change the Profile, then depending on which profile I select, I get either sound out of the left channel only, right channel, or neither channel; but none of the profiles provide sound out of both channels at the same time.

How do I troubleshoot this kind of problem?

Comment: Troubleshoot: Get Pulseaudio out of the picture (e.g. `pasuspend`, or stop the demon), see if it already happens on the ALSA level. Look at `amixer` if any settings are funny. If you are using Intel SDA, debug the codec (cat `/ /proc/asound/card*/*codec*`). Debug what the Pulseuadio profiles actually do, by observing the changes with `amixer` and in the codec (if applicable). It's possible the update introduced a quirk for your hardware type that doesn't apply to your particular hardware, so also check `dmesg` after boot for sound initialiaztion.